# Selling a plugin for Android on Google Play

Tags: android, plugins, google-play

I am new to developing Android applications and I have an idea for a project which involves a free base application and a number of plugins which the user would have to purchase. As far as I have been able to figure out, I should package the plugins as services which the main application will access and I have a vague idea of how this is achieved.

Here is my question.

Is it possible to sell these `plugins` on `Google Play store` and, more importantly, how would I make sure that the user will only be able to purchase the plugin once the base application has been installed?

Or is there a way to specify that the base application will be installed together with the `plugin`?

I have read about filters but somehow I can't seem to find an appropriate filter for the task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to sell these plugins on Google Play store

Yes. GO Launcher does exactly this for themes. Themes can be put up by third part devs, and users can download them to use them

> how would I make sure that the user will only be able to purchase the plugin once the base application has been installed?

There is no option to do this. The best you can do is run a check for your base application when your app is installed and run, and if it isn't installed prompt the user to install it.

Comment: Thanks, this helps clear up things and gives me a direction do go in.